# Click function being called twice but only on the first click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing an action down form Context. The `onClick` has to go a few levels but for some reason when you click it the first time it fires twice. Only the first time, though, after that it fires once per normal. It also only seems to do this if the `console.log` is inside the Reducer function...

Demo can be found here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-haze-veejt

Comment: Did you bind your onClick function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You push reducer of useReducer to out of ImagesProvider

Example code file ImagesContext

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

const initialState = {
  galleries: [
    {
      images: ["screenshot-1.jpg", "screenshot-2.jpg"]
    },
    {
      images: [
        "screenshot-3.jpg",
        "screenshot-4.jpg",
        "screenshot-5.jpg",
        "screenshot-6.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const Images = createContext(initialState);
const { Provider } = Images;

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (true) {
    case action.type === "removeImage":
      console.log("click", action.id);
      return { ...state };
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unhandled type: ${action.type}`);
  }
}

const ImagesProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, updater] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return <Provider value={{ state, updater }}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export { Images, ImagesProvider };
```

codepen url: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-dust-qmrxm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
Good luck!